# How to make Call Button on amp Page with AMP cache

Tags: caching, button, call, amp-html

My website : https://www.onsumlock.com

I add two call button on website as follow:

```
<a href="tel:52227111" rel="alternate" media="handheld">
        <amp-img src="img/HOTLINE.png" width="500" height="208" alt="開鎖服務" layout="responsive"></amp-img></a>
```

The button work on my server but not work at amp cache, any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.onsumlock.com

Comment: Please try the 52227111button

Comment: Chrome not work